# Remove cancel button from UISearchBar in tableViewController

Tags: uitableview, uisearchbar, cancel-button

How can I stop the cancel button appearing from a UISearchBar, in the simplest way possible, from within a tableViewController, in iOS9?

[image: UISearchBar with cancel button]

There are quite a few alternative answers out there, but no simple objective C ones work in iOS9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void) didPresentSearchController:(UISearchController *) searchController {
  self.searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For swift, Based on answer from [Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4244674/ben),

```
func didPresentSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) {
        searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
    }
```

and dont forget to set delegation to your search controller.

```
searchController.delegate = self
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.